# ProgressBar in Android Studio: The path must start at (0,0) and end at (1,1)

Tags: java, android, progress

As soon as I add a ProgressBar to my project, Android Studio will show me the following error in layout editor (see picture):[image: Error in Layout Editor]

In addition, it tells me to disable experimental Layout Rendering Engine. If I do so, it will throw a Render Error instead (see second picture):

[image: Picture 2]

Even though the error is thrown, the ProgressBar itself works fine.
Can I just ignore the error or is there a workaround/fix for it?

Also, my Fragment looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.Page1">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1_page1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2_page1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3_page1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.18" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4_page1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_page1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1_page1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_chooseVersion"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/chooseVersion_text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3_page1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1_page1"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3_page1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_chooseType"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/chooseType_text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2_page1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2_page1"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2_page1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_AFH"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/afh_download"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_page1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_gdrive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/gdrive_download"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_page1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.911"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1_page1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline4_page1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That errors are about `editMode` aka. preview in IDE. Yes it is safe to ignore them. But if you want to fix it probably adding some `tools` properties might help. In this case I guess `tools:max` might help.
Also if it was a custom view written by yourself (which is not, just saying) you could check it with `isInEditMode` inside your view.

Comment: Unfortunately, `tools:max` didn't seem to work.
But I will just ignore the error then, thank you anyway for your answer!